# How to enter values in rich text container using geb and spock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a rich text editor in our application which we are automating using Geb and Spock. Below is the **HTML** for the same .

```html
<div class="coral-RichText-editable coral-Form-field coral-Textfield coral-Textfield--multiline coral-RichText gecko is-edited" data-config-path="/mnt/override/apps/intel/productscatalog/components/content/editorialProductCard/cq:dialog/content/items/tab/items/column/items/fieldset/items/column/items/cardLayout/field/items/column/items/description.infinity.json" data-use-fixed-inline-toolbar="null" style="outline-style: none;" contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    <br _rte_temp_br="brEOB">
  </p>
</div>
```

I have multiple options .But not able to send keys into that particular field. It's giving an error:

> Unable to set the value of element p which is not a valid form element.

Comment: <div class="coral-RichText-editable coral-Form-field coral-Textfield coral-Textfield--multiline coral-RichText gecko is-edited" data-config-path="/mnt/override/apps/intel/productscatalog/components/content/editorialProductCard/cq:dialog/content/items/tab/items/column/items/fieldset/items/column/items/cardLayout/field/items/column/items/description.infinity.json" data-use-fixed-inline-toolbar="null" style="outline-style: none;" contenteditable="true">
<p>
<br _rte_temp_br="brEOB">
</p>
</div>

Comment: You can edit your question